# Displaying progress text for WIX bootstrapper install actions

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.8

I have created a WIX burn ui installer using bootstrapper. It copies a folder, copies some registry entries and installs a service. There are no custom actions. Is there a way to show the progress text in such a scenario? It should display what items are being copied, what registries are being created etc. Any help would be much appreciated. (Saw lot of similar questions but all of them are based on displaying progress text for Custom Actions)

Comment: Have you validated that this improves the experience of your users?

Comment: Yes, because they would want to know what's happening if the progress bar is stuck at a certain percentage. It will help them know that installation still is happening though progress percentage is not moving. To address such scenarios it would be great to show the things happening

Answer (score 2):

The `OnExecuteMsiMessage` callback gives the BA access to what Windows Installer is doing.  Here's how [WixStdBA](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp#L678) handles it:

```
virtual STDMETHODIMP_(int) OnExecuteMsiMessage(
    __in_z LPCWSTR wzPackageId,
    __in INSTALLMESSAGE mt,
    __in UINT uiFlags,
    __in_z LPCWSTR wzMessage,
    __in DWORD cData,
    __in_ecount_z_opt(cData) LPCWSTR* rgwzData,
    __in int nRecommendation
    )
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    BalLog(BOOTSTRAPPER_LOG_LEVEL_STANDARD, "WIXSTDBA: OnExecuteMsiMessage() - package: %ls, message: %ls", wzPackageId, wzMessage);
#endif
    if (BOOTSTRAPPER_DISPLAY_FULL == m_command.display && (INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING == mt || INSTALLMESSAGE_USER == mt))
    {
        int nResult = ::MessageBoxW(m_hWnd, wzMessage, m_pTheme->sczCaption, uiFlags);
        return nResult;
    }

    if (INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART == mt)
    {
        ThemeSetTextControl(m_pTheme, WIXSTDBA_CONTROL_EXECUTE_PROGRESS_ACTIONDATA_TEXT, wzMessage);
    }

    return __super::OnExecuteMsiMessage(wzPackageId, mt, uiFlags, wzMessage, cData, rgwzData, nRecommendation);
}
```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know mate :)

Comment: How do these installers we find these days show "copying somefile", "registrying keys" kind of things? Because the messages from ExecuteMsiMessage seem pretty technical. Are there any hacks to show messages for non technical people?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is bit old question. But recently I came across same thing and I figured it out. Thought of sharing it with anyone who looking for answers :) .

You can add ExecuteMsiMessage Event handler to log the progress texts (eg: update registry, copying files and etc).

```
model.BootstrapperApplication.ExecuteMsiMessage += MessageHandler;

private void MessageHandler(object sender,ExecuteMsiMessageEventArgs e)
{
    // your message here
    ProgressStatusText = e.Message;
}
```